# Missising DSYMs files for Fabric Craslytics

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

I am trouble to get crash report to Fabric Crashytics Dashboard.
After googling so much i found the DSYMs file missing for the fabric. 
I have try so may way to upload DSYMs file using the Xcode - Organizer,
Iphone simulator build DSYMs. After successful upload I get same missing DSYMs file.

Please help me to proper way to upload DSYMs file to Fabric.

Thanks,

Comment: DSYMs is not the issue ignore missing DSYMs file message try integrating Fabric again

Answer (score 0):

iPhone simulator build DSYMs won't work as the architecture differs.
Fabric takes some time to process the symbols, please allow sufficient time.

Fabric will tell you which DSYMS are missing, ensure you upload those ones.